# Google Cloud - EventArc Path Pattern or Pub/Sub Filtering

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, event-arc

I want to create an EventArc Trigger with "google.cloud.bigquery.v2.JobService.InsertJob" on 3 tables within a dataset that contains 10+ tables. Do I need to create 3 EventArc Triggers on tables or is it possible to use path patterns/pubsub filters with a trigger on dataset to solve this?

I already tried creating Pub/Sub filters on the EventArc messages but I couldn't manage to access the resourceName of the EventArc message because it is on the second level:

```
{"protoPayload": {"resourceName": "table1..."}}
```

With path patterns it is probably not possible to include OR-type statements right?

Comment: Did you try a path pattern with a =~? It means a regex, it could work (never tested!) https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logging-query-language#regular-expressions